# Web scrapping con R con "href" que no es constante

Tags: r

estoy tratando de extraer un **"href"** que cambia en cada sesión, cuando corro el código me lo devuelve vacío. Se puede extraer de alguna manera?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


base <- "https://apanalytics.shinyapps.io/DARKO/" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node("a#download_talent") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

Es un botón "download" que descarga un .csv en la pestaña "Current player projections"

Muchas gracias

Comment: El tema no es tan simple, no se trata de una tabla estática sino de una web dinámica, por lo que necesitarías automatizar la interacción con la página: 1. Abrir la página  2. Hacer click en el botón "Current player selection" 3. Tal vez completar algún filtro 4. Hacer click en el botón"Download data".  Esto se puede automatizar, pero es otro mundo de de la captura estática, necesitas usar ´Rselenium' , la configuración no es tan sencilla, a menos que ya tengas experiencia con docker, revisa esto: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html

Comment: Revisa también esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183174/leer-tabla-html-con-rvest, hay una alternativa a Rselenium usando phantomjs.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio