# Escrapear en R información de productos y precios en la Web

Tags: r, rstudio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de sacar información de los productos y precios de inkafarma pero no me bota ninguna información, si me podrian ayudar por favor .
Este es mi código en R lo que estuve haciendo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
web <- read_html("https://inkafarma.pe/categoria/farmacia")
producto<-web%>%
html_nodes("._ngcontent-exh-c78")%>%
html_nodes("fp-product-name")%>%
html_nodes("span")%>%
html_text()
producto

# Inicializamos un data frame
datos<-data.frame(producto)
```

Comment: Bienvenido Hebert a SO en español. Ese catálogo tiene toda la pinta de generarse  directamente en el navegador con JavaScript. Por eso en el navegador lo puedes ver pero `read_html()` no encuentra los nodos: en el html que descarga no están, todavía no se generó el contenido. En https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183174/leer-tabla-html-con-rvest puedes ver algo sobre el tema y soluciones a un caso similar.

Comment: Pareciera que se trata de una página no estática, `rvest` no te va a servir en este caso, te sugiero que intentes por el lado de `rselenium`.